# How to iteratively bring in different layers from a folder and assign them each different variable names?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have been working with some code that exports layers individually filled with important data into a folder. The next thing I want to do is bring each one of those layers into a different program so that I can combine them and do some different tests. The current way that I know how to do it is by importing them one by one (as seen below).

```
fn0 = 'layer0'
f0 = np.genfromtxt(fn0 + '.csv', delimiter=",")
fn1 = 'layer1'
f1 = np.genfromtxt(fn1 + '.csv', delimiter=",")
```

The issue with continuing this way is that I may have to deal with up to 100 layers at a time, and it would be very inconvenient to have to import each layer individually.

Is there a way I can change my code to do this iteratively so that I can have a code similar to such:

```
N = 100
for i in range(N)
fn(i) = 'layer(i)'
f(i) = np.genfromtxt(fn(i) + '.csv', delimiter=",")
```

Please let me know if you know of any ways!

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?  you probably shouldn't have both of them as tags

Comment: how are your files numbered?  are they single digits, or do all numbers have leading zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use string formatting as follows

```
N = 100
f = [] #create an empty list
for i in range(N)
    fn_i = 'layer(%d)'%i #parentheses!
    f.append(np.genfromtxt(fn_i + '.csv', delimiter=",")) #add to f
```

What I mean by `parentheses!` is that they are 'important' characters.  They indicate function calls and tuples, so you shouldn't use them in variables (ever!)

Comment: The one problem I've experienced with this method is that my data layer is a list of 3 columns (x, y, z). Each column has 10 data points. When I append this data into the empty list, it turns into a tuple where I can only access the layer as a whole, I cannot access/call the specific x, y, or z columns in each layer.

Comment: are you sure it's a tuple and not an ndarray? what do you get when you try `type(f[0])` ? can you access the contents of those arrays by using commands like `f[i][0]`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Mohammad Athar is correct. However, you should not use the `%` printing any longer. According to PEP 3101 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) it is supposed to be replaced by `format()`. Moreover, as you have more than 100 files a format like `layer_007.csv` is probably appreciated.
Try something like:

```
dataDict=dict()
for counter in range(214):
    fileName = 'layer_{number:03d}.csv'.format(number=counter)
    dataDict[fileName] = np.genfromtxt( fileName, delimiter="," )
```

When using a dictionary, like here, you can directly access your data later by using the file name; it is unsorted though, such that you might prefer the list version of Mohammad Athar.